# dask groupby columns are not there even after reset_index

Tags: group-by, dask, dask-dataframe

I am using group by-apply on multiple columns with a user-defined function. However, these columns do not appear in the output data frame, even if I use reset_index.
Unfortunately, I could not create a minimal reproducible example without using my own data. My workaround was explicitly adding the group by columns in the output data frame in the user-defined function.

Comment: seems like the issue was that the dataframe had an existing index column BEFORE the groupby and dask does not like that. When I did reset_index BEFORE the groupby everything works fine.

Comment: Interesting, knowing the fix now, is it possible to come up with a MRE?

Comment: here's a good guide to [creating reproducible examples in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) - from there you can just import the dataframe with [`dask.dataframe.from_pandas`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.from_pandas.html)